# Calling sibling parameter of object in another parameter

Tags: javascript

Hi  I have an object like this

```
var utils = {
    activePageIndex: 0,
    baseJSONPages: baseJSON.Pages,
}
```

Now I  want to add one more parameter to my object like this

```
activePage : baseJSONPages[activePageIndex]
```

I tried this, but did not work...

```
activePage : utils.baseJSONPages[utils.activePageIndex]
```

I know I can do it like this

```
activePage : function(){
    return utils.baseJSONPages[utils.activePage];
}
```

But I dont want to call it with parenthesis every time I need. Is that possible to define it whithout converting it as a method.

**Thank you all for yor down votes**

Comment: Why does your first method "not work" exactly?

Comment: I dont know, but the console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseJSONPages' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way finally...

```
var utils = {
    activePageIndex: 0,
    baseJSONPages: baseJSON.Pages,
    _activePage : function(){
        return utils.baseJSONPages[utils.activePage];
    }
}

utils.activePage = utils._activePage();
```

Now I can call `utils.activePage` without parenthesis.